# is it possible to mention the Android Version of Device to be filtered in Manifest file?

Tags: android, android-manifest

I learnt i can filter out devices to which my android application is available by using
certain conditions in Manifest file.

But is it possible to specify the Android Version used in the device as a filter?

**Scenario :**

i actually wan to restrict device based on Android version used in the device.. 
for example in Galaxy S3 the android Version is 4.0.4...

so if i do the configuration, the only devices with Android version 4.0.4 will be able to download my app in Google store..

if so please suggest.

Comment: You mean that the "filter" should change depending on the device? Are we talking about this?

<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="integer" 
          android:targetSdkVersion="integer"
          android:maxSdkVersion="integer" />

Comment: i actually wan to restrict device based on Android version used in the device.. 
for example in Galaxy S3 the android Version is 4.0.4... 

so if i do the configuration, the only devices with Android version 4.0.4 will be able to download my app in Google store..

Comment: API level (SDK Version) 15 corresponds to Android 4.0.3, 4.0.4. Similarly, you can change the SDK version as mentioned in my answer. To know which API level corresponds to what Android version, click the link I mentioned in the answer. Hope that's what you want. :)

Comment: And yes also mention the 'android:maxSdkVersio' so only that version can use it not any version above the 'android:minSdkVersion' specified in manifest.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your question is unclear to me.

This is how you can set which version of Android can install your app.

```
<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="integer" 
          android:targetSdkVersion="integer"
          android:maxSdkVersion="integer" />
```

Note: The version numbers are SDK version NOT the Android versions.

[Refer docs for more details. Here](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/uses-sdk-element.html) you can also see what SDK Level corresponds to which Android Platform version.

Answer (score 2):

You use this element in the manifest fo accomplish that, have a look at the Android developer's site:

[`<uses-sdk>`](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/uses-sdk-element.html)

> Lets you express an application's compatibility with one or more
>   versions of the Android platform, by means of an API Level integer.
>   The API Level expressed by an application will be compared to the API
>   Level of a given Android system, which may vary among different
>   Android devices.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, as like above suggested answers we can restrict using `uses-sdk`

Below screen shows, which API Level represents which Android Version.
This should be useful to some one.

[image]

This can be seen in android SDK Manager.